# Can´t deploy Windows Phone 8.1 app to phone - timeout

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, lumia

When I try to deploy app from Visual Studio to my Lumia 930 it´s starts to deploy but the timeout is received with following messages

```
Error   1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
SmartDeviceException - This operation returned because the timeout period expired.  Hipstaroll.WindowsPhone

Error   2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
Hipstaroll.WindowsPhone
```

I have:

- VS2013 update 4 (didn´t work before this update either)
- tried with different USB-cables
- tried with different computers and USB-ports
- tried to remove USB-devices
- Turned Hyper-V off
- I can navigate with explorer in the phone and copy images, etc.
- Windows Phone Power tool has the same problem
- Tested to deploy new blank project with same result
- Removed the device in the device manager
- Turned everything off and on
- Register and unregister device as developer phone
- Try to develop app by using Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1)

Comment: Are you running windows 8 or 10 on your developer machine?

Comment: @OakNinja windows 8.1, latest stable release

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone registered for development? This might be the cause.

To [unlock your device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx) follow these steps.

1. Turn on your phone and unlock the phone screen.
2. On your phone, ensure that the date and time are correct.
3. Connect your phone to your computer by using the USB cable that came with your phone.
   4.On your computer’s Start screen, switch to All apps view.
4. Under Windows Phone SDK 8.0, click **Windows Phone Developer Registration**.
5. Verify that the Status message displays Identified Windows Phone 8 device. Click the Register button to unlock the phone.
6. If your phone is already registered, the Status message indicates this and you see an Unregister button.
7. Click Register.
8. In the Sign In dialog box for your Microsoft account (formerly known as a Windows Live ID), enter the email address and password for your Microsoft account. Click Sign In.
9. If you’re a registered developer, be sure to use the Microsoft account associated with your developer account.
10. After your phone is successfully registered, the Status message displays **Congratulations! You have successfully unlocked your Windows Phone**.

Comment: Yes, it is. I´ve tried to unregister and register as developer again

Answer (score 0):

I updated to developer preview of OS and now it works. Seems to be something strange with latest official OS version

Comment: It worked for a while after soft reset the phone, but i hope to find a better solution...